# how to place button on side when hidden side panel is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, sass

I am trying to animate using a side panel that animates into the viewport with the use of a button.

this is what it looks like on load

[image]

and when the user clicks on any of the two buttons the notes panel will slide visible like this

[image]

here is what i have so far

```
[3]: https://codepen.io/terenceting/pen/ZqaOJo
```

can anyone help me. and what does this feature called?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for right? a slide in panel, this can be achived with CSS and just some class manipulation on the container element, try this out:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyPEZx

I'm basicly just toggling a class called active on the `note-wrapper` element, there is no use for jquery slide now days since css and transiotions can do most of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.. let me know if it's what are you expected

https://codepen.io/aflyzer/pen/JmORyG

just use `toggleClass` and some css

Comment: the button must join the moving panel.

Comment: Fot that, you need to put the button inside to your panel. Give position relative to your panel, position relative to your button and place it at the left of your panel.

Answer (score 0):

before anything some **tips** about this code. 
The **HTML structure**: Look that the "slideDivs" content all the components you need, I use **borders** and **colours** for better perspective.
The Jquery: It use the state "onoffBtn" for know if the block is open or not. Like I said in the code, this is better with a function that do this in 1 step an less code but Snipped don't like functions with jquery xD.
The importar parts of **CSS**:

```
#slideDivs{
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;/*Change it if you need*/
  position: absolute;
}
.comp{
  display:inline-block;
}
.tabs{
  width: 440px;
  float: right;
  height: 11em;
}
.tabs{/*All tabs divs must be "display: none"*/
  display: none;
}
#btnTabs{
  width:40px;
  height:180px;
}
.btnTab{
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /* this rotate the btn text, rest are for other explorers (firefox, IE..)*/
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.btnTab:nth-child(2){
  margin-top:2px;
}
```

***Hope this can help you, here is (https://codepen.io/Alvargon/pen/QZaNmL)
the code in codePen with some improvements, good luck ;)***

```js
/*The "optimal way", is use a function, but the code Snippet doesn't like it XD;
*/
var onOffBtn1 = "off";
var onOffBtn2 = "off";
var exnum = 0;
var num = 0;

$("#btn1").click(function(){
    num = 1;
    switch(onOffBtn1){
      case "off": {
        $("#tab"+exnum).hide("fast"); 
        $("#tab"+num).show("fast");
        onOffBtn2="off"; onOffBtn1="on"; 
        exnum = 1;
        break;
      }
      case "on": {
        $("#tab"+num).hide("fast");
        $("#tab"+exnum).hide("fast");
        onOffBtn2="off"; onOffBtn1="off"; break;
      }
    }    
  });

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    num = 2;
    switch(onOffBtn2){
      case "off": {
        $("#tab"+exnum).hide("fast"); 
        $("#tab"+num).show("fast");
        onOffBtn1="off";onOffBtn2="on"; 
        exnum = 2;
        break;
      }
      case "on": {
        $("#tab"+num).hide("fast");
        $("#tab"+exnum).hide("fast");
        onOffBtn2="off";onOffBtn1="off"; break;
      }
    }    
  });
```

```css
#mainDiv{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#slideDivs{
  background-color:#add8e680;
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  /*width: 500px;*/
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
.comp{
  display:inline-block;
}
.tabs{
  border: 3px double orange;
  width: 440px;
  float: right;
  height: 11em;
}
.tabs{
  display: none;
}
#btnTabs{
  width:40px;
  height:180px;
  border: 3px solid darkgreen;
}
.btnTab{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);   
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.btnTab:nth-child(2){
  margin-top:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu Tururu
  <div id="slideDivs">
    <div id="btnTabs" class="comp">
      <button id="btn1" class="btnTab">BTN 1</button>
      <button id="btn2" class="btnTab">BTN 2</button>       </div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tabs comp"><strong>TAB 1</strong><p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabs comp"><strong>TAB 2</strong><p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```